# Как из строки взять по два целочисленных символа и перемножить их?

Tags: java, строки

Дана строка:

`String str = "2347865238";`

Понимаю, что вытащить индексы ячеек можно с помощью метода `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`, но не могу сообразить, как описать в цикле это. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с пояснением.

Comment: `str.charAt(0)` — получаете первый символ. Вычитаете из него символ `'0'` — получаете число из отрезка `0..9`. Вот что вы дальше хотите сделать не очень понятно...

Comment: Надо перемножить двузначные числа, 23*47, 47*86 и так далее

Comment: для какого языка?

Comment: Для языка Java.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос: уточните что такое ячейки, сколько их может быть всего, всегда ли они состоят из двух символов. Думаю также, что ожидаемый ответ для заданной строки тоже пригодился бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{   
   String str = "2347865238";
   int result = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i += 2) {
      String newStr = str.substring(i, i + 2);
      int value = Integer.parseInt(newStr);
      result *= value;
   }    
   System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Работает, в указании длины строки -1 можно не делать. У вас и самый первый вариант был рабочий, это я при записи у себя ошибся и выдало ошибку.

Comment: Если у Вас будет нечетное количество символов в строке, компилятор выдаст исключение. Поэтому здесь нужно `str.length() - 1`, так как Вы делаете итерацию `i += 2`

Comment: Этого не знал, учту. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-). Код на [ideone](http://ideone.com/1lrrpO).

```
int result = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
    int number = (str.charAt(i) - '0') * 10 + (str.charAt(i + 1) - '0');
    result *= number;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Объясните, зачем умножать на 10 ? Потому что строка состоит из 10ти символов ?

Comment: Нет. Потому что число состоит из двух разрядов. То есть `23 = 2 * 10 + 3`. В коде умножение на 10 имеет такой же смысл.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: ок............)